# How to set image in right side corrner of MDI parent?

Tags: .net, winforms, picturebox

I am using Windows Form project. In my MDI Parent Form that I want to show my company logo at the right side corner. So I have drag a picturebox and set the image.

But I am not success my requirement, The image not in correct position. I have tried padding also. Dock is increase my image height to full form height. So Its also not help me.

Before Running the Solution. (I want this as a run time)..
[image]

At the Time of Solution Running. (Unwanted Space in Right side)

[image]

And MDI Form is Maximized at running time. with the help of below code.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to set **Anchor** property of picturebox to **Top, Right** by default its set to `Top, Left`

Comment: @Sagotharan - Does this answer your question? If so you should mark it as the 'accepted answer'

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to work, you'll discover soon when you start creating MDI client windows.  The picture box is always on top of the client windows.  What is required is drawing the image in the MDI client window, the dark gray window in your screenshots.  That takes a fair amount of unusual code, you have to get a reference to that control so you can implement your own Paint event for it.  You also need to be aware that the window size changes so your can repaint the image in the new location.  And you have to do something about the flicker you normally see.  Make your code look similar to this:

```
using System.Reflection;
...

    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (Control ctl in this.Controls) {    // Find the MDI client window
                if (ctl is MdiClient) {
                    ctl.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(MdiClient_Paint);
                    ctl.Resize += delegate { ctl.Invalidate(); };
                    // Hackorama to avoid flicker:
                    var dblBuf = ctl.GetType().GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    dblBuf.SetValue(ctl, true, null);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        void MdiClient_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
            var client = (MdiClient)sender;
            using (var bmp = Properties.Resources.Logo) {    // change this
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, new Point(client.ClientSize.Width - bmp.Width, 0));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 Very nice solution. In the past, I've always been used the BackgroundImage property but the image was not at the place where I wanted. With this solution, I'm able to define an offset to change the location of the image and this look great!

Answer (score 1):

Put picture box in to a container and Dock the Container first. Then Container Only Dock to right. And put and Image to picture box.